# CodeBlocks debbuger error - Cant open files

Tags: debugging, codeblocks

Here is the image of the error I'm having right now. There are some commands that the debbuger does not run when I click on `Step Into` or `Next Line` button and show this error instead. I have no ideia how to fix it. I found something about *Settings>Compiler>Advanced Options* But I don't really know what to do there.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Ubuntu. Ubuntu doesn't install source code for its libraries (or executables) by default. `strtok` is part of libc. You can retrieve libc's source code by doing:

```
apt-get source libc6
```

This will put a whole tree of source code, rooted at (for example) `eglibc-2.19/` in your current directory. Gdb may or may not be able to find the correct files within that tree, depending on what pathnames are embedded in your system's libc files. On Ubuntu 14.04, the libc components all point to `/build/buildd/eglibc-2.19` as the root of all the source code[1], so I'd recommend creating that directory and moving all the libc source into it. After doing that, you should be able to see the source code, for example:
[image: codeblocks source code panel]

[1] I used the command `readelf -wi /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so | grep comp_dir | more` to find the directories.

Comment: I downloaded the content with your `apt-get` command, I got `eglibc-2.19` folder in my `home folder`. Just don't know what to do next... When I execute the `readelf -wi` command I got a lot of lines but I dont understand it... I'm noob to linux =\

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Do you have administrator access? If so, do `sudo mkdir /build/buildd ; sudo cp -a ~/eglibc-2.19 /build/buildd/eglibc-2.19`

Comment: `mkdir: cannot create directory '/build/buildd/ : No such file or directory`. Same for CP

Comment: Oh. Do `sudo mkdir -p /build/buildd` , then the `sudo cp` command.